# How to position plot.tag and plot.title side-by-side, on the same line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a custom `ggplot` theme, and would like to position the `plot.tag` and `plot.title` next to each other, on the same line. I want to keep the two labels unique from each other as I require different text formats. I also want to keep the tag optional, so if it's not specified in `labs()`, then the title will be shown by itself in the top-left position.

I've tried:
`plot.tag.position = 'topleft'` but this creates unwanted space to the left of the plot; and
`plot.tag.position = c(0,1)` but this overlaps the tag and title labels (in the code below, I've used this but hacked the title label with spaces).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "                    Median duration of unemployment",
       tag = "Figure 1.0:",
       y = "Weeks") + 
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = 'mm')),
        plot.tag.position = c(0,1), 
        plot.tag = element_text(face = 'bold', hjust = 0, vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = 'mm')))
```

This is the result that I'm aiming for:
[image: This is the result that I'm aiming for]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be the `ggtext`  package which allows you to glue the tag and the title together but still have the option to add different styles via some markdown or HTML/CSS. To make this a bit more convenient I make use of a helper function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

labs2 <- function(title = NULL, tag = NULL, ...) {
  if (!is.null(tag)) {
    tag <- paste0("**", tag, "**")
    title <- paste(tag, title)
  }
  labs(title = title, ...)
}

ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs2(title = "Median duration of unemployment",
       tag = "Figure 1.0:",
       y = "Weeks") + 
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
        plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(hjust = 0, vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = 'mm')))
```

[image]